# Product Search in Backend (Admin Area) - Something went wrong. - Magento 2.1-rc3

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I upgraded my Magento from 2.0.2 to 2.1-rc3 some days ago, and today I had a strange issue with the Product Search (Products > Catalog) page, I'm getting the message "Attention: Something went wrong" and the searchs stop.

It was working some hours ago, the different thing is I imported some products.

I already flushed cache, re-compile, re-indexed and nothing.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE 2016-07-22 - I was able to fix it, deleting all the products and importing them again. I have no idea what was causing it.**

Comment: can you shown stacktrace from log?

Answer (score 0):

first ,You should install 2.1.0 stable version. 
https://www.magentocommerce.com/download

you can use 
`
php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext

`